# Amazon Certificate Manager: My Shortest Possible Domain Name Is Too Long

Tags: aws-certificate-manager

I'm trying to request a certificate for `my.super.long.delegated.domain.com` through the AWS console. I have control over `long.delegated.domain.com` but not over `domain.com` - it's someone else's and they've delegated `long.delegated.domain.com` to me. I know from [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/APIReference/API_RequestCertificate.html#ACM-RequestCertificate-request-DomainName) that:

> The first domain name you enter cannot exceed 64 octets, including periods. Each subsequent Subject Alternative Name (SAN), however, can be up to 253 octets in length.

I want a certificate for `my.super.long.delegated.domain.com`, but it is longer than 64 octets (but shorter than 253 octets). The shortest domain I have control over is `long.delegated.domain.com` which is still longer than 64 octets.

How can I get a certificate covering `my.super.long.delegated.domain.com`, which doesn't prevent me from making another certificate in another AWS account for `my-other.super.long.delegated.domain.com`?

Answer (score 3):

Looping back around to share the workaround I found, which is the following:

1. I got the delegating authority to delegate a shorter domain to me - `short.delegated.domain.com`.
2. I used a domain like `some.prefix.short.delegated.domain.com` as the first domain on my certificate. I did not use this domain for *anything* other than filling in the first domain.
3. I added my actual needed domain name, now `my.super.long.short.delegated.domain.com`.

To be explicit: I did not manage to find a workaround if the delegated domain is longer than 64 octets, other than **use a different domain for the first entry**.